# Why does Lex turn on the flashlight?

Tags: plot-explanation, jurassic-park

In *Jurassic Park (1993)* when the T-Rex breaks free from the cage, the two kids are alone in the car.

The T-Rex is interested in the Grant/Malcolm car, but Lex turns on a flashlight and attracts the T-Rex.

Why does she turn on the flashlight?

Comment: So that they could have scene where the creature's face is illuminated by a flashlight

Comment: Darkness is scary. Light is good. They are kids, they aren't governed by logic at this point and don't know any better.

Comment: 1993…..man. Time flies. I remember when I was 8 and saw the trailers for that film….wow.

Answer (score 39):

### What is the intent of Lex?

She has no intent...she's just looking for *anything* as the [script](http://www.dailyscript.com/scripts/jurassicpark_script_final_12_92.html) makes clear..

> Lex is rummaging around in the back cargo area, looking for
> something, anything.  She finds a flashlight.

### Why does she turn on the flashlight?

Because that's what you do with a flashlight and she doesn't know any different or that it will attract the T-Rex.

> LEX
> I'm sorry - - I'm sorry - -
>
> TIM
> Turn it off, Lex!  Turn it off!
>
> Tim climbs over the seat and joins Lex.
>
> TIM (cont'd)
> Where is the button then?
>
> LEX
> I don't know, I don't know.  I'm sorry - -
>
> TIM
> Why did you do this?
>
> LEX
> I don't know!  I'm sorry!

Comment: Exactly. Logic isn't really at play here - they're young kids and the only adult in the car just bailed on them, so they'd be even more terrified and scrambling to do something, *anything*, to scare the T-Rex or otherwise improve their situation.

Comment: Yeah, the answer to "why did a frightened child in the dark turn on a flashlight?" should be pretty obvious.

Comment: This scene is reminiscent to me of the stupidity of the design GenTec put into the park (which I guess is the point of the plot). The Explorers should have had their gas engines kept in place for emergencies so a qualified guest or a staff member can drive it back to the exhibition center. Say in the event of a track system failure like what happened in the film. The gas engines would automatically start and a guest behind the wheel could shift into D and the vehicles could be driven freely to safety.

Comment: I think this is right - not only is it what you'd do when you got a flashlight but if you're looking for something you'd want to illuminate the area.

Comment: Not only that, but they really should have a back-up generator that would keep the fence electrafied and cars moving if the power goes out. Am I Right?

Answer (score 15):

They are kids and Gennaro has left them alone in the car. They didn't know what to do.

So they looked for a way to call for help from Dr. Grant or Malcolm. You can also hear Lex calling Dr. Grant's name in a low voice due to fear. So, they used the flashlight to signal them but she didn't know that it would attract the T-Rex.